# Leiningen 2-steps build: how to combine lein-less and lein-asset-minifier

Tags: clojure, build, less, minify, leiningen

I'm making a Clojure/ClojureScript website that I deploy on Heroku. I'm using Leiningen for project management.

I want to write my stylesheets in LESS. I need the build process to compile the LESS files into CSS, then minify these CSS files; obviously, I do not want the generated CSS files to be under version control.

**LESS files --`lein-less`--> CSS files --`lein-asset-minifier`--> minified CSS files**

I have tried to implement this with the [`lein-less`](https://github.com/montoux/lein-less) and [`lein-asset-minifier`](https://github.com/yogthos/lein-asset-minifier) Leiningen plugins. My attempt consisted of declaring `leiningen.less` and `minify-assets.plugin/hooks` as hooks of the `:uberjar` task, in proper order *(see code below)*. But running `lein uberjar` fails with the following error:

```
Uberjar aborting because jar failed: resources/public/css/site.css (No such file or directory)
```

So it appears the order of build steps is not enforced.

***Is it possible to implement this multi-step build with these Leiningen plugins? If not, how are people doing it?***

---

### Code

Here is the relevant part of my `project.clj` :

```
(defproject sncf-cljs "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
            ;; ...
            :min-lein-version "2.5.0"
            :source-paths ["src/clj" "src/cljs"]
            :dependencies [
                       ;; ...
                       ]

            :plugins [
                      [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]
                      [lein-environ "1.0.0"]
                      [lein-ring "0.9.1"]

                      [lein-asset-minifier "0.2.2"]
                      [lein-less "1.7.2"]]


            :less {:source-paths ["src/less"]
                   :target-path "resources/public/css"}



            :uberjar-name "sncf-cljs.jar"

            :minify-assets {:assets
                            {"resources/public/css/site.min.css" "resources/public/css/site.css"}}

            :cljsbuild { 
                        ;; ...
                        }

            :profiles {                                 
                       ;; ...

                       :uberjar {:hooks [leiningen.less
                                         leiningen.cljsbuild
                                         minify-assets.plugin/hooks]

                                 :env {:production true}
                                 :aot :all
                                 :omit-source true
                                 :cljsbuild {:jar true
                                             :builds {:app
                                                      {:source-paths ["env/prod/cljs"]
                                                       :compiler
                                                                     {:optimizations :advanced
                                                                      :pretty-print false}}}}}

                       :production {:ring {:open-browser? false
                                           :stacktraces?  false
                                           :auto-reload?  false}
                                    :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:compiler {:main "sncf-cljs.prod"}}}}
                                }})
```

Comment: There was an issue with hook invocation order. Now, it is fixed. Please, look at https://github.com/yogthos/lein-asset-minifier/pull/13

Answer (score 2):

I did some research because it is an interesting question. So I looked around, and could not find informations how to configure this. So I continued to search and I found a plugin for this task.

https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-cascade

The readme on the github page should be sufficient to solve this task.